# How ElasticSearch Scroll API works internally

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch scroll API as documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-scroll.html).
It's well understood that each scroll request takes as input a scroll id returned in response of previous scroll response. Once done with scrolling all the chunks, the last scroll id needs to be cleared.

## Use Case

- Consume a big data set (in order of 0.1 to 2 million) matching a given query in chunk size of 5000. Individual chunk query performance is good.
- Data is most likely to be queried from single indice and shard.
- The data which is being queried never gets updated in real time.

## Questions / Concerns

- How elastic search maintains the scroll session or state internally ? Will all the matching documents (or their ids) stored or parked aside in-memory and returned in subsequent scroll requests ? Should I be concerned about RAM/CPU that are currently allocated to the cluster.
- Are there any performance penalty while using the scroll API ? I understand that there is default max number of scroll session allowed at a time which is 500. This default is acceptable in my case as number of requests per seconds in quite low.

Answer (score 2):

During performance testing in my environment, the scroll API with scroll size set to 7,000, GC pause time upto 1.5 minutes and high  CPU usage was observed. ( Obviously this is also affected by the cluster configuration and type of query that ran)

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html) and an informative [blog](https://dev.to/molly_struve/iterating-through-elasticsearch-documents-using-scroll-and-ruby-3coi?signin=true)

> The results that are returned from a scroll request reflect the state of the data stream or index at the time that the initial search request was made, like a snapshot in time. Subsequent changes to documents (index, update or delete) will only affect later search requests.

The data matching the search-request passed in first scroll API is kept aside in memory. Quoting from the mentioned blog :-

> As I mentioned above, scrolling works by taking a "snapshot" of your data and then serving it to you in pieces. This means that Elasticsearch must "hold" all of that in memory.* Having to hold the scroll "snapshot" in memory while doing a lot of data updates can cause your memory to bloat. Memory bloat can lead to issues if you don't have a large surplus of memory to work with.

**Short Answer**
Yes, do consider heap and cpu usage while using the scroll API. Factor like request per second and optimal scroll size should be considered for given cluster configuration.